# Making rectangular grid with the second and third row offset?

Tags: java, javafx, grid-layout

I am trying to build the following rectangular grid of stars in which the second and third rows are offset to the right to achieve the design pattern.

[image: Desired grid]

However, with my code all I have achieved is this:

[image: My code]

My code is:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int colNum = 0;

    //Shapes
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        if (row == 1 || row == 3)
            colNum = 6;
        else
            colNum = 7;
        for (int col = 0; col < colNum; col++) {
            Polygon star = new Polygon(25, 0, 15, 20, 0, 20, 10, 40, 5, 60, 25, 50, 45, 60, 40, 40, 50, 20, 35, 20);
            star.setFill(Color.WHITE);

            star.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            GridPane.setRowIndex(star, row);
            GridPane.setColumnIndex(star, col);

            GridPane.setHalignment(star, HPos.RIGHT);
            grid.getChildren().addAll(star);
        }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 1024, 800, true);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);


    primaryStage.show();
    }
```

}

How can I offset the second and fourth row so that it looks like the first image?

Comment: There are a few different ways to do this, one is a VBox containing HBoxes which have different [insets](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#insetsProperty) for odd/even HBoxes.

Comment: You use five point stars rather than the six point stars of the sample pattern. Is that intentional?

Comment: Hi @jewelsea, no it was a mistake but I will try to fix that later.. more concerned about the grid design first. Could you please clarify what you meant by VBox containing HBoxes? If I understand correctly, I should have a gridPane and within that gridPane, I should have 2 hBox nodes of different insets?

Comment: You don’t need a gridpane at all, just one VBox and as many HBoxes as you need.  Though you could do it the way you describe as well, personally so would just skip the GridPane. Sorry, I can’t write the code for a more detailed answer at the moment.

Comment: you could try to use more columns and column spanning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jewelsea suggested, you can use a `VBox` for the layout and `HBox` for rows:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Pane row1 = createRow("0,0", "1,0", "2,0", "3,0", "4,0", "5,0", "6,0");
        Pane row2 = createRow("0,1", "1,1", "2,1", "3,1", "4,1", "5,1");
        Pane row3 = createRow("0,2", "1,2", "2,2", "3,2", "4,2", "5,2", "6,2");
        Pane row4 = createRow("0,3", "1,3", "2,3", "3,3", "4,3", "5,3");

        VBox pane = new VBox(row1, row2, row3, row4);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #37474f; -fx-padding: 20;");

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static Pane createRow(String... texts) {
        HBox pane = new HBox();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Arrays.stream(texts).map(App::createStar)
                .forEach(pane.getChildren()::add);

        return pane;
    }

    private static Pane createStar(String text) {
        Polygon star = new Polygon(15, 0, 30, 10, 45, 0, 45, 17.32, 60, 25.98, 45, 34.64, 45, 51.96, 30, 43.3, 15, 51.96, 15, 34.64, 0, 25.98, 15, 17.32, 15, 0);
    
        star.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        star.setStrokeWidth(2);
        star.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
  
        // Removes the small gap between rows
        star.setScaleX(1.1);
        star.setScaleY(1.1);

        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 16));
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
    
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(star, label);
    
        return pane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image: Grid with stars]